# how do you stack CSS animation

Tags: css, animation

I have a css element that I am trying to animate.
The box starts out with height 30px. On click I want the box to first shrink to height 0px then animate to 60px

```
document.getElementById("box1").style = "transition: height 0s;  transition-delay: 0s; height:0px";    
document.getElementById("box1").style = "transition: height .50s;  transition-delay: .50s; height:60px";
```

I tried the above but the second line overwrites the first.

Comment: keyframes is what you're looking for i think https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Comment: What HTML element is that `box1`? Depending on that, you can use focus, and animate with keyframes as you click it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that should help: https://jsfiddle.net/qshruafp/

```js
document.getElementById("box1").addEventListener('click', ManageBoxClick);

function ManageBoxClick() {
  console.log('Entered ManageBoxClick');
  
  document.getElementById("box1").animate([
  // keyframes
    { height: '30px' },
  { height: '0px' },
  { height: '60px' }
  ], {
    // timing options
    duration: 1000
  });
  
}
```

```css
#box1 {
   position relative;
   display: block;
    
  background-color: blue;
  
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
```

Comment: left in by accident will remove now

Comment: You can find all of that here if need be: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate